# Passing json object in href function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, href

I need to pass a json object to function, which is as mentioned below in a href, but this JS code is not getting evaluated. So can anyone suggest a workaroud or a solution for this?

```
function function_test(option,jsonObj){
   displayMessage(str);
}

function function_prepare_div(){   
  var str ="";
  var jsonResposneObj = getJson();//function to get jsonResponseObj
  for(i=0;i<jsonResponseObj.length;i++){
    str += "<a href='function_test( " + i + "," + jsonResposneObj.dataObj[i] +")'>1. " + jsonResposneObj.dataObj[i].objName + "</a></br>";
  }  
    return str;
}
```

P.S. I cannot return the jsonResponse after function call.

Comment: what is function_test and you're putting that into a href?

Comment: What does pass object in href function mean? Show us all the relevant code.

Comment: I have added the code in edit, please check this. I am updating a div in html page with the dynamically generated content, and passing a JSON object received in a response for the respective function call.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do you want to pass the *result* of `function_test()` to the href attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inlined JS, append the element using proper DOM methods, and then attach an event listener.

Eg something like

```
const a = container.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
a.href = function_test(1, jsonResponse);
a.textContent = '1. ' + function_test(1, jsonResponse);
```

(make sure `function_test` returns a URL)

Answer (score 0):

**Functions (or any JavaScript for that matter) don't belong in an `<a href="">` in the first place.**

Hyperlinks are for navigation, not JavaScript hooks. Using them just to trigger some JavaScript is an incorrect use of the `<a>` tag. It was commonplace 20+ years ago (before we had web standards), but is woefully outdated and downright incorrect today. Using a hyperlink to trigger JavaScript is semantically incorrect and can cause issues for people who rely on assistive technologies (like screen readers) to navigate a page.

Just about any element that is valid in the `body` of a web page supports a `click` event and most are better suited to what you want to do.

What you need to do is register your function as the callback to the `click` event of some element, like this:

```js
// An example of a JSON response
var jsonResponse = '{"key1":10,"key2":true,"key3":"foo"}';

// Get reference to any element that supports a click event that
// can be safely used as a JavaScript trigger
var span = document.getElementById("fakeLink");

// Set up an event handling callback function for the click event of the element
span.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //  Call the function and pass it any arguments needed
  processJSON(1, jsonResponse, this);
});

// Do whatever you need to do in this function:
function processJSON(val, json, el){
 console.log(val, json);
 el.textContent = val + json;
}
```

```css
/* Make element look & feel like a hyperlink */
#fakeLink { cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; } 
#fakeLink:active { color:red; }
```

```html
<span id="fakeLink">Click Me</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var json = {
  foo: 'bar'
};


var func = function(data) {
  alert(data.foo);
}

$('body').append("<button onclick='func(" + JSON.stringify(json) + ")'>BUTTON</button>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```